# pkg upgrade broke X server on FreeBSD ((II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes: "NULL")

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, nvidia, x-server, startx

## Problem

After a recent update of `pkg` and circa 60 other programs my X server broke.

I used to start dwm with `startx` but I get the following error message instead:

> ```
> xauth: file /home/user/.serverauth.1323 does not exists  
> xauth: (argv):1: bad display name "pc-freebsd:0" in "list" command  
> xauth: (stdin):1: bad display name "pc-freebsd:0" in "add" command
> ```

## Information

- I cannot do anything afterwards in this tty.
- I know that `startx` reaches `.xinitrc` because my `~/.xinitrc` is configured to beep when it is being processed.
- `enable_xauth` is set to `1` in `/usr/local/bin/startx`.

### Xorg.0.log

> ```
> [   131.714] 
> X.Org X Server 1.17.4
> Release Date: 2015-10-28
> [   131.714] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
> [   131.714] Build Operating System: FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p39 amd64 
> [   131.714] Current Operating System: FreeBSD pc-freebsd 10.3-RELEASE-p4 FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p4 #0: Sat May 28 12:23:44 UTC 2016     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64
> [   131.715] Build Date: 04 October 2016  06:28:38AM
> [   131.715]  
> [   131.715] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
> [   131.715]  Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>   to make sure that you have the latest version.
> [   131.715] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>   (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
> [   131.715] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct 10 23:11:24 2016
> [   131.759] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
> [   131.760] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
> [   131.760] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
> [   131.760] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
> [   131.760] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
> [   131.761] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
> [   131.761] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
> [   131.761] (==) Automatically adding devices
> [   131.761] (==) Automatically enabling devices
> [   131.761] (==) Not automatically adding GPU devices
> [   131.851] (**) FontPath set to:
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/misc/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/TTF/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/OTF/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/Type1/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/misc/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/TTF/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/OTF/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/Type1/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi/,
>   /usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi/
> [   131.851] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules"
> [   131.851] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
> [   131.851] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
> [   131.851] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
> [   131.851] (II) Loader magic: 0x801510
> [   131.851] (II) Module ABI versions:
> [   131.851]  X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
> [   131.851]  X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
> [   131.851]  X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
> [   131.851]  X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
> [   131.852] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0dd6:1028:04b7 rev 161, Mem @ 0xd4000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
> [   131.852] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
> [   131.852] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
> [   131.885] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
> [   132.263] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
> [   132.264]  compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
> [   132.264]  Module class: X.Org Server Extension
> [   132.264] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  367.44  Wed Aug 17 22:01:17 PDT 2016
> [   132.273] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
> [   132.273] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
> [   132.329] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
> [   132.329]  compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
> [   132.329]  Module class: X.Org Video Driver
> [   132.336] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  367.44  Wed Aug 17 21:41:06 PDT 2016
> [   132.336] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
> [   132.337] (--) Using syscons driver with X support (version 0.x)
> [   132.337] (--) using VT number 9
>
> [   132.359] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
> [   132.359] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
> [   132.359] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
> [   132.374] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [   132.374]  compiled for 1.17.4, module version = 1.0.0
> [   132.374]  ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
> [   132.374] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
> [   132.374] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
> [   132.374] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
> [   132.380] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [   132.380]  compiled for 1.17.4, module version = 1.0.0
> [   132.380]  ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
> [   132.381] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
> [   132.381] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
> [   132.381] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
> [   132.383] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
> [   132.383] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
> [   132.383] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
> [   132.383] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
> [   132.383] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
> [   132.385] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
> [   133.170] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 550M (GF106) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
> [   133.170] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
> [   133.170] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.06.32.00.04
> [   133.170] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
> [   133.182] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
> [   133.182] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
> [   133.182] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA: Reserving 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
> [   133.322] (II) NVIDIA(0): Built-in logo is bigger than the screen.
> [   133.323] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
> [   133.375] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
> [   133.375] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
> [   133.375] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
> [   133.389] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
> [   133.389] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
> [   133.389] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
> [   133.389] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
> [   133.389] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
> [   133.389] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
> [   133.390] (--) RandR disabled
> [   133.406] (II) Initializing extension GLX
> [   133.406] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
> [   134.137] (II) config/devd: probing input devices...
> [   134.137] (II) config/devd: adding input device (null) (/dev/kbdmux)
> [   134.137] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
> [   134.149] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/input/kbd_drv.so
> [   134.154] (II) Module kbd: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [   134.154]  compiled for 1.17.4, module version = 1.8.1
> [   134.154]  Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
> [   134.154]  ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
> [   134.154] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for 'kbdmux'
> [   134.154] (**) kbdmux: always reports core events
> [   134.154] (**) kbdmux: always reports core events
> [   134.154] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
> [   134.154] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
> [   134.154] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
> [   134.154] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
> [   134.154] (**) Option "config_info" "devd:kbdmux"
> [   134.154] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "kbdmux" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
> [   134.161] (II) config/devd: kbdmux is enabled, ignoring device ukbd0
> [   134.161] (II) config/devd: kbdmux is enabled, ignoring device ukbd1
> [   134.161] (II) config/devd: kbdmux is enabled, ignoring device atkbd0
> [   134.161] (II) config/devd: adding input device (null) (/dev/sysmouse)
> [   134.161] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
> [   134.161] (II) Loading /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
> [   134.162] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [   134.162]  compiled for 1.17.4, module version = 1.9.1
> [   134.162]  Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
> [   134.162]  ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
> [   134.162] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for 'sysmouse'
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: always reports core events
> [   134.162] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/sysmouse"
> [   134.162] (==) sysmouse: Protocol: "Auto"
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: always reports core events
> [   134.162] (==) sysmouse: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: Buttons: 5
> [   134.162] (**) Option "config_info" "devd:sysmouse"
> [   134.162] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "sysmouse" (type: MOUSE, id 7)
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
> [   134.162] (**) sysmouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
> [   134.162] (II) sysmouse: SetupAuto: hw.iftype is 4, hw.model is 0
> [   134.162] (II) sysmouse: SetupAuto: protocol is SysMouse
> [   134.163] (II) config/devd: device /dev/ums0 already opened
> [   134.163] (II) config/devd: device /dev/ums1 already opened
> [   134.163] (II) config/devd: device /dev/ums2 already opened
> [   134.163] (II) config/devd: device /dev/psm0 already opened
> ```

## What I've tried already

### Kill the process and run `startx` again

1. Change tty.
2. Log in as root.
3. Run `ps`:

   > ```
   > 1337 v0 S 1:00:00 /usr/local/bin/X :0 -auth /home/user/.serverauth1323 (Xorg)
   > ```
4. Kill the process with `kill -9`.
5. Change the tty back to where the user is logged in.

   The user can use their command prompt again now.

   There is another message from xauth:

   > ```
   > xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "pc-freebsd:0" in "remove" command
   > ```
6. Run `startx`.

Doesn't solve my problem.

### Remove the `/home/user/.serverauth.*` files

I removed all those files but it didn't help.

### Try to the X server as root

1. Log in as root.
2. Run `startx`.

   The interesting thing is that although I got the very same error messages from `xauth` and I had to change the tty since the current one froze, a lot of additional processes started:

   - xinit
   - xterm (in fact 3 of them)
   - twm
   - xclock

   I tried to kill all these processes but when I run `pkill xclock` the whole machine froze and I had to use the power button.

### Set `enable_xauth` to `0` in `/usr/local/bin/startx`.

According to [this thread on forums.freebsd.org (link)](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/36005/#post-281026) a hacky solution might be setting `enable_xauth` to `0` in `/usr/local/bin/startx`.

It didn't work for me however. The xauth messages disappeared but `dwm` didn't start as well.

### Reinstall all packages

I decided to try to reinstall all packages with `pkg upgrade -f` (inspiration: [this thread (link)](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/48074/#post-268527)).

After rebooting I ran `startx` and after a second the whole screen went blank with only a quite big cursor block in the upper left corner of the screen (looks like the font got bigger).

When I switch tty and then immediately switch back I can see a stream of `usage: sleeps seconds` being printed all the time.

### Unplug the remote screen

The machine is Dell L702X. I use an external monitor instead of the laptop's default screen. My `~/.xinitrc` contains the following lines which disable the default screen and stream the video onto the external monitor (connected over HDMI).

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --auto
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --rotate left
```

Unfortunately, neither unplugging the monitor nor commenting out those lines fix the issue.

Comment: Is there anything informative in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after running `startx`?

Comment: @D_Bye I've added the log file.

Comment: @D_Bye I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it had little to do with `xauth`.

I should have read `/usr/ports/UPDATING` before updating.

The issue was related to these messages from `Xorg.0.log`:

> ```
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
> [   133.182] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
> ```

As we can read in `/usr/ports/UPDATING`:

> 20160829:   AFFECTS: users of x11/nvidia-driver   AUTHOR:
>   cem@FreeBSD.org
>
> The NVidia driver has been updated to version 367.35.  Starting with
>   version 358.09, new kernel module was added, nvidia-modeset.ko.  This 
>   new driver component works in conjunction with the nvidia.ko kernel
>   module to program the display engine of the GPU.
>
> Users that experience hangs when starting X11 server, or observe
>
> ```
> (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:  (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
> ```
>
> messages in their `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file should replace *nvidia*
>   with *nvidia-modeset* in `/boot/loader.conf` or `/etc/rc.conf` files,
>   depending on how they prefer to load NVidia driver kernel module.

So after I changed `nvidia_load="YES"` to `nvidia-modeset_load="YES"` in `/boot/loader.conf` I was able to get into a dwm session.

Meanwhile, I performed a system upgrade to FreeBSD 11.0, so I am not exactly sure if it is everything one need to solve the problem.